# How to find the slowest operator through google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have call center website and adding google analytics.
When calling client- operator need to use website for resolving client problems. When operator open one of the tab in website - I creat operation_id (in code), for grouping pages in one action.

I create all possible goal from website in google analytics, adding operator_id as Client_id in google analytics. Adding user variables like operator_id and operation_id.

**What I need:**

- to know the time from start operation to end operation, time that I need for reaching the goal
- to know the slowest operator as operator_id for teaching them

Comment: The slowest operator? that could mean too many things. Your question should be more about coding. Like e.g. how to get the time of a function since the last click (just an example)

Comment: I have goal, from start to finish it used time. I need the longest time for finishing goal.